# How does one obtain K and stoichiometry from the Isothermal Calorimetry binding curve?

Tags: calorimetry

In Isothermal Calorimetry, I can appreciate that data is fitted to equations to obtain $K, \Delta H, \Delta G, \Delta S$ and stoichiometry, $n$.

However, I have seen from multiple sources that $K$ and $n$ can be obtained directly from the graph of enthalpy change against molar ratio of ligand added as such:

[image]
Obtained from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_titration_calorimetry

Where $n$ is the midpoint of the binding curve and $K_a$ is the slope (?) of the curve at what seems to be the midpoint.

But can also be seen here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_IpWcWKNXI&ab_channel=MalvernPanalytical (Just to show that the graph can be seen from multiple sources)

I can't figure out intuitively or mathematically why the $K$ and $n$ can be obtained directly from the graph as such. I have tried (taking $M_t = 1$ and $V_0 = 1$) substituting $Q = \frac{\Delta H}{2}$ into equation 7 from [this document](https://cmi.hms.harvard.edu/files/cmi/files/microcal-itc200-system-user-manual.pdf) as well as differentiating equation 7 with respect to $X_t$. The results do not seem to agree with what the graphical method suggests.

Comment: Well, not directly, but with a bit of calculating...